# How to make a raspberry pi a remote desktop controlled with normal pc running ubuntu?

Tags: pi-4, ubuntu, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I have a raspberry pi 4b and a normal full-size pc by dell.  The big pc has ubuntu on it, and the pi has raspbery pi os bullseye.  I want to make the raspberry pi be a remote desktop that can be controlled by the big pc. Not just a teminal window, but a remote desktop. I have seen how to do it on windows, but how about it on ubuntu 21.10?  How can I do this?

Comment: what do you mean by `extension`? ... it is a separate computer ... not Raspberry Pi specific

Comment: Yes. it is a dell. I want to run the pi as a remote desktop.

Comment: then google `linux remote desktop` ... your question is not RPi specific, it is a linux question, so it is asked at the wrong place

Comment: I don't use anything google.  The question is about the raspberry pi end of the deal. I got the pc already set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Raspberry Pi OS allows you to [enable a VNC server (Virtual Network Computing)](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/remote-access.html#vnc). Then you need to install a VNC client on your Ubuntu PC. There are different options, such as TigerVNC. You connect PC and Pi via network (Ethernet), open the VNC client and connect to the remote desktop using the known IP address of the Pi.